# Youtube API wrong callbacks on Android

Tags: android, youtube, callback, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm creating an android app in which I have to precisely know when playback starts/pauses/buffers etc (I need to play a video only for specific time). However PlaybackEventListener is calling not proper callbacks. For example on Sony Xperia S here is the order of callback which are called by listener: *BUFFERING, BUFFERING, PLAYING, BUFFERRING, BUFFERING (and here is when the playback actually starts, yes not on PLAYING callback).*

On the other phone (not so popular - Telefunken Diamon) callbacks are called more randomly sometimes it's: *BUFFERING, BUFFERING, PLAYING (playback starts)*, but sometimes the same as on Xperia S.

On the emulator - GenyMotion API 4.3 the order and callbacks are proper - BUFFERING, BUFFERING, PLAYING (playback starts).

I was trying with loadVideo(String, int) method and cueVideo(String, int) method, but the result is the same. **However what I did notice is that when I'm using those methods without initial offset (second parameter) like loadVideo(String) the order on all three phones looks the same: BUFFERING, BUFFERING, PLAYING**, but I need to seek the video, so anyone dealed earlier with something like that and can help? Thanks in advance!